# Creating greater than sudoku game board

Tags: java, javafx, sudoku

Hello I'm trying to make greather than sudoku solver. I have made in Java backtracking algorithm which is solving greather than sudoku board from array input of inequalities and now I want to make the graphic interface for it and here is the problem.

[image]

I wanted to make my game board looking like this. I was trying to do this in JavaFX on GridPane but I think I am not allowed to change the board lines of grid to change them to inequalities (˄  ˅ < >). Then I was trying to make normal sudoku board of squares and show on it grid with inequalites signs only but I couldn't make them to match the lines.

Is here any good way to make board like this on screenshot? I want to generate boards from inequalites input then after clicking solve show them filled with numbers.

I will be very thankful for every help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why your question is not quite good: it is too broad and you don't show any own attempt.

Comment: or in other words: nobody is going to do your work for you ;)

Comment: The grid lines of `GridPane` are a feature meant for debugging. You shouldn't rely on it. It seems like you could achieve the layout easily by using `Path`/`Polyline` though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach to create a control for each cell, with the defined shape given by the greater/lower symbols, and an editable text, is the following:

For any given single cell, you can create a square region with a `Path`, a `Text` and a `TextField` nodes.

The path will be stroked only, not filled, and it won't get out of the square region, which is convenient to pile up 9 cells in a 3x3 square box.

If a cell side requires a greater symbol, the part out of the cell will be defined by the neighbour cell, that will use a lower symbol.

For instance, these three cells:

[image: cells]

can be combined into one 3x1 row:

[image: row]

With two rows more, we will have a 3x3 box:

[image: 3x3 grid]

that matches perfectly the requirement. Now with 8 boxes more like this we will have the full sudoku.

Let's create this cell now.

**GreaterCell**

For convenience let's define three possible side types: greater and lower for the inner sides, equal for the border sides.

```
public enum Symbol {
    GREATER, EQUAL, LOWER
}
```

Let's start with the `Path`. We'll use `MoveTo` and `LineTo` depending on the type of each of the four sides.

```
private static final double SIDE = 60;
private Path path;

private void createPath() {
    path.getElements().clear();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0d, 0d));

    // top
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE / 3d ,0));
    switch (top) {
        case GREATER: path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(2d * SIDE / 3d, 0d)); break;
        case EQUAL: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(2d * SIDE / 3d, 0d)); break;
        case LOWER: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE / 2d, SIDE / 5d)); 
                    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(2d * SIDE / 3d, 0d)); 
                    break;
    }
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE, 0d));

    // right
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE, SIDE / 3d));
    switch (right) {
        case GREATER: path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(SIDE, 2d * SIDE / 3d)); break;
        case EQUAL: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE, 2d * SIDE / 3d)); break;
        case LOWER: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE - SIDE / 5d, SIDE / 2d)); 
                    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE, 2d * SIDE / 3d)); 
                    break;
    }
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE, SIDE));

    // bottom
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(2d * SIDE / 3d, SIDE));
    switch (bottom) {
        case GREATER: path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(SIDE / 3d, SIDE)); break;
        case EQUAL: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE / 3d, SIDE)); break;
        case LOWER: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE / 2d, SIDE - SIDE / 5d)); 
                    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE / 3d, SIDE)); 
                    break;
    }
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0d, SIDE));

    // left
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0d, 2d * SIDE / 3d));
    switch (left) {
        case GREATER: path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0d, SIDE / 3d)); break;
        case EQUAL: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0d, SIDE / 3d)); break;
        case LOWER: path.getElements().add(new LineTo(SIDE / 5d, SIDE / 2d)); 
                    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0d, SIDE / 3d)); 
                    break;
    }
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0d, 0d));
}
```

With this path, now we can define the region with the text node.

It is important to note we add a `Clip` to cutoff the half border of the path that goes out the cell.

```
public class GreaterCell extends Region {

    public enum Symbol {
        GREATER, EQUAL, LOWER
    }

    private static final double SIDE = 60;
    private final Path path;
    private final Text text;

    private final Symbol top, right, bottom, left;
    private final Rectangle clip;

    public GreaterCell(String number, Symbol top, Symbol right, Symbol bottom, Symbol left) {
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
        this.left = left;

        getStyleClass().add("greater-cell");

        path = new Path();
        path.getStyleClass().add("path");

        createPath();

        text = new Text(number);
        text.getStyleClass().add("text");

        getChildren().addAll(path, text);

        clip = new Rectangle(SIDE, SIDE);
        setClip(clip);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        resizeRelocate(0, 0, SIDE, SIDE);
        Bounds b = text.getBoundsInParent();
        text.resizeRelocate(SIDE / 2d - b.getWidth() / 2d, SIDE / 2d - b.getHeight() / 2d, SIDE / 2d, SIDE / 2d);
    }
}
```

The row could be defined now as:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    GreaterCell tile31 = new GreaterCell("3", LOWER, LOWER, GREATER, EQUAL);
    GreaterCell tile41 = new GreaterCell("6", LOWER, GREATER, GREATER, GREATER);
    GreaterCell tile51 = new GreaterCell("5", GREATER, EQUAL, LOWER, LOWER);
    HBox root = new HBox(0, new Group(tile31), new Group(tile41), new Group(tile51));
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(40));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());        
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And we'll have again the above pic:

[image: row]

Adding a `TextField` to allow editing is now an easy task.

```
private final TextField textField;

private final Symbol top, right, bottom, left;
private final Rectangle clip;

public GreaterCell(String number, Symbol top, Symbol right, Symbol bottom, Symbol left) {
    ...
    textField = new TextField();
    textField.setVisible(false);

    getChildren().addAll(path, textField, text);

    setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            text.setVisible(false);
            textField.setText(text.getText());
            textField.setVisible(true);
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    textField.setOnAction(e -> {
       textField.setVisible(false);
       text.setVisible(true);
       text.setText(textField.getText());
    });

    textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        if (! nv) {
            textField.setVisible(false);
            text.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();

    ...
    textField.resizeRelocate(SIDE / 4d, SIDE / 4d, SIDE / 2d, SIDE / 2d);
}
```

[image: textfield]

Note that it could be more convenient to create a `GreaterCellSkin` to manage the rendering, while the control will just have the text property, but for now this simple approach is good enough.

**Style.css**

```
.greater-cell {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
}

.greater-cell > .path {
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 1.4px;
    -fx-fill: null;
}


.greater-cell > .text {
    -fx-font-size: 2em;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

.greater-cell > .text-field {
}
```

**Box**

To create a box, it is convenient to use a `GridPane` control, that will laid out 3x3 cells. This part is left out of this answer.

**Sudoku**

Finally, another `GridPane` will laid out 3x3 boxes. This part is also left out of this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for help!